# Please help me in saving a text file using javascript in chrome

Tags: javascript

As per my project requirement i need to save a file using javascript, i searched many blogs, many of them are telling about the ActiveXObject, but ActiveXObject is supported only ob IE, as per my application i am using chrome, can some one give a brief example how to save a file using javascript.

Thanks in Advance.
Khaja

Comment: it may not possible because chrome will directly open txt file..

Comment: What are you doing with the file before saving it, and are you creating an extension or is this simply a webpage?

Comment: Hi Sac and Quantas, Thanks a lot for your quick replies,  just i am appending some text to a .txt file

Answer (score 0):

Put file on server and open link to it using Javascript.

Comment: Hi Anton, Could you please give a sample code to do this, it will be very help full to me if you give this sample code.     Thanks,khaja

Comment: copy file to http://www.yoururl.com/yourfile.someext.
add next javascript code:
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com/yourfile.someext"
and user will see dialog with saving file

Comment: Thanks a lot Anton..Sorry to say this now..i am new to javascript...So could you please provide me a code snippet, So that i can understand and will try to implement the same..

Comment: Can any one please give an alternate solution for saving a file using javascript.